# Проверка условия принадлежности Key к Value в Python

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь, вызов функции `is_anybody_home(dictionary, 'b')` и сама функция в которой необходимо проверить наличие значения `'b'` в словаре и затем проверить какой ключ соответствует этому значению:

```
dictionary = { 
    '1' : 'a',
    '2' : 'b',
    '3' : 'c'
}
def is_anybody_home(collection, letter):
    if letter in collection.values(): #находим букву в списке
        for number in collection:    #проходимся по числам 
            if     #здесь должно быть условие
                print(letter, ' это значение ключа ', number)


is_anybody_home(dictionary, 'b')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dictionary = { 
    '1' : 'a',
    '2' : 'b',
    '3' : 'c'
}
def is_anybody_home(collection, letter):
    for key, value in collection.items():
        if value == letter:
            print(letter, ' это значение ключа ', key)


is_anybody_home(dictionary, 'b')
```

Answer (score 1):

Полное условие такое (проверить, что ключ есть в словаре, потом проверить значение по этому ключу):

```
number in dictionary and dictionary[number] == letter
```

Также можно использовать такое условие:

```
dictionary.get(number) == letter
```

`get` аналогично получению значения через квадратные скобки, но если запрошенного ключа нет, не выбрасывает исключение `KeyError`, а возвращает `None` (или значение, которое будет передано вторым параметром в `get`). Будет некорректно работать, если `None` - это допустимое значение в вашем словаре (будет давать совпадение для отсутствующих ключей), например следующий код покажет `True`:

```
d = {1: None}
number = 2
letter = None
print(dictionary.get(number) == letter)
```